# using performSelector in a c function to call delegate

Tags: objective-c, c, exc-bad-access

**Scenario**

```
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(aboutTextUpdated:)]) {
    [delegate aboutTextUpdated:aboutText];
}
```

to simplify this kind of checks in my project I created a couple of c functions as below and used them.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
id callSelectorOnDelegateWithObject(SEL selector,NSObject *delegate,id object)
{
    if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:selector] == YES)
    {
        if (object != nil)
        {
            return [delegate performSelector:selector withObject:object];
        }
        else 
        {
            return [delegate performSelector:selector];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

id callSelectorOnDelegate(SEL selector,NSObject *delegate)
{
    if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:selector] == YES)
    {
        return [delegate performSelector:selector];
    }
    return nil;
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

they were called as below

```
callSelectorOnDelegateWithObject(@selector(aboutTextUpdated:), delegate, aboutText);
```

**Problem**
I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error some times, but not in a reproducible manner. The exception occurred when the c function was called but before executing the first statement. When I replace the function call with actual if statement, then the error never occurs. To meet project deadline I went ahead with that change. But couldn't get this error out of my head.

What is causing the error?

**More Background**

- The project uses ARC, minimum target is iOS 5.0
- The project uses AFNetworking 1.* to get data from server, core data to save it in the app and NSNotification for inter app communication
- The methods given to perform selector always return void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to see the details of the crash to know more. My best guess is that there are occasional calls to `callSelectorOnDelegateWithObject()` where `object` is `nil` but the method identified by `selector` actually does take an argument. In that case, you're using just `-performSelector:`, not `-performSelector:withObject:`. So, the method receives garbage for its argument.

If some code called `callSelectorOnDelegateWithObject()` rather than `callSelectorOnDelegate()` then you should pass the `object` argument through unconditionally. The caller passing `nil` does not mean you can drop the argument. The `nil` probably (or, at least, possibly) is important.

That said, this whole approach doesn't seem like a good idea. I would not find this scheme simpler than the code snippet at the top of your question.

You can simplify that code snippet by not explicitly checking if `delegate` is non-`nil`. The `-respondsToSelector:` check will already return false if `delegate` is `nil`, because messaging `nil` always results in false.

Finally, you should never compare against `YES` (or `TRUE`, etc.). You're taking an expression which is already a boolean expression and then making it a compound boolean expression. Let me ask if you would ever write code like the following:

```
if (([delegate respondsToSelector:selector] == YES) == YES)
    ...
```

If you would not write that second `== YES` (and an infinite sequence of further comparisons to `YES`), then you should understand why you shouldn't have written the first.

Beyond that, any non-zero value is a true value. `YES` is only one such value. For any given method which returns a boolean value, you can't be sure that the true value it returns is actually `YES` as opposed to any other true value.

Comment: not sending a nil argument when needed, that explains it, thanks. and I do agree with your points, it was redundant.